# Color RGB in LaTeX

Tags: color

Please, I'd like to use the blue color RGB (0,32,96) in LaTeX.

How can I do this?

I find this on the web:

```
\definecolor{ultramarine}{rgb}{0.07, 0.04, 0.56}
```

But it is not the right color I search.

Comment: `\usepackage{xcolor}` and then `\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}`

Comment: @egreg Just to make sure, I immediately get it when googling this again: The emphasis lies on `RGB` in capital letters. `RGB`: [0, 255]; `rgb`: [0.0, 1.0]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `color` package also supports decimal values in the `RGB` color model that accepts integer values in the interval [0,255]. On the other hand, `xcolor` offers much more features, so it's better to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,32,96}

\definecolor{wrongultramarine}{rgb}{0.07, 0.04, 0.56}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{ultramarine}{Ultramarine \rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\textcolor{wrongultramarine}{Wrong Ultramarine \rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you could just compute 32/255 and 96/255, getting

```
\definecolor{ultramarine}{rgb}{0, 0.125, 0.376}
```

that gives the very same color as with `{RGB}{0,32,96}`.

Comment: RGB works with `color` with the standard pdftex or dvips .def files

Comment: Can I also use a `\foreach\x` variable in the color code similar to `\definecolor{tmpcolor}{HSB}{\x,255,255}`?