# Use macro to define a color

Tags: macros, color, expansion

I have a color stored in a macro in the following way

```
\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
```

for example. Is there any way to define the same color using the macro

```
\colordefine{maincolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}
```

and replacing last code with it?

Comment: Look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239461/color-rgb-in-latex

Comment: IMHO this is more or less a question about expansion. So I've added the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% or xcolor

\newcommand*{\colordefine}[2]{%
  \expandafter\colordefineAux#2{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\colordefineAux}[3]{%
  \definecolor{#3}{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
\colordefine{maincolor}\mycolor

\begin{document}
  The main color is \textcolor{maincolor}{blue}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

But I would stick with the official interfaces `\definecolor` and/or `\colorlet` (the latter provided by package `xcolor`) for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

The naive idea `\definecolor{maincolor}\mycolor` would not work, because in this case `\mycolor` will not expand to `{rgb}{0,0,1}` to become argument two and three of `\definecolor` but is still a single (second) argument of `\definecolor`. So the main question would be: How to expand `\mycolor` either completely or at least one step, before TeX reads the second argument of `\definecolor`?

At sure, one could write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
\expandafter\definecolor\expandafter{\expandafter m\expandafter a\expandafter i\expandafter n\expandafter c\expandafter o\expandafter l\expandafter o\expandafter r\expandafter }\mycolor
\begin{document}
Example \textcolor{maincolor}{example} example.
\end{document}
```

With this code, expansion of `\definecolor` (and so reading the arguments) will be delays until the `{` have been read, which will be delayed until `m` have been read, which will be … until `}` have been read. So TeX will not longer expand/execute `\definecolor{maincolor}\mycolor` but `\definecolor{maincolor}{rgb}{0,0,1}`.

However such a solution is not really practical. So we need a solution, that does the expansion delay with the need of an explicit `\expandafter` queue. Herbert has already shown one [solution with hidden reordering of arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407063/9057).

Another suggestion could be to expand the arguments similar to `\@expandtwoargs` of the LaTeX kernel but without the argument braces for the second argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\expandsecondargtoseveralargs}[3]{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand#1{#2}#3}%
  \reserved@a
}
\makeatother
\expandsecondargtoseveralargs\definecolor{maincolor}\mycolor
\begin{document}
Example \textcolor{maincolor}{example} example.
\end{document}
```

or without expansion of `{maincolor}` and only one level expansion of `\mycolor` using ε-TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\expandsecondargtoseveralargs}[3]{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\unexpanded{#1{#2}}\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
}
\makeatother
\expandsecondargtoseveralargs\definecolor{maincolor}\mycolor
\begin{document}
Example \textcolor{maincolor}{example} example.
\end{document}
```

Both result in:

[image]

And if you do not want a prefix command but a new command, you can use one of these definitions of `\expandsecondargtoseveralargs` to define your `\colordefine`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{{rgb}{0,0,1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\expandsecondargtoseveralargs}[3]{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\unexpanded{#1{#2}}\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\colordefine}{\expandsecondargtoseveralargs\definecolor}
\colordefine{maincolor}\mycolor
\begin{document}
Example \textcolor{maincolor}{example} example.
\end{document}
```

However, I do not understand why you are storing the colors this way in macros. So maybe this is not really a solution to your problem.