# How can I define a colour from a macro?

Tags: macros, color, expansion

I am trying to define a colour (using the `xcolor` package) where the colour is provided by a macro in hex HTML format. I have a macro `\colorGet{#1}{#2}` which takes two arguments and returns the colour in hex format, which I would like to pass to the `\definecolor` macro.

Unfortunately, my naïve approach of simply passing one macro as the argument of the other doesn't work, and I understand this is because of the order in which LaTeX expands the macros. However, I don't understand how to ensure they are expanded in the correct order. I have attempted to modify [this answer by Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407063/219478) to a similar question, but was unsuccessful. I don't understand `\expandafter` enough to know where I'm going wrong. A minimal (non-)working example of my attempt is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\newcommand{\colorGet}[2]{D3523C} % A macro which returns a different hex-code for each combination of arguments, simplified for this example.
\newcommand{\colordefine}[2]{%
    \expandafter\colordefineAux#2{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\colordefineAux}[2]{%
    \definecolor{#2}{HTML}{#1}%
}
%
\begin{document}
    \colordefine{mycolor}{\colorGet{SchemeName}{ColourName}}
\end{document}
```

Attempting to compile this gives the following error:

```
! Argument of \xs_newmacro_ has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.14 ...rdefine{Accent2}{\colorGet{Bold}{Accent2}}
```

Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

EDIT: As highlighted by Phelype Oleinik, the error message above is caused by the `xstring` package, which was used in the original definition of `\colorGet`. Since asking the question, I've realised that the `xstring` package isn't needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error message you show seems to be from the `xstring` package, which you don't load in your example code.  The code from the post can be adapted to work, but the solution will _not_ work with `xstring`, so please provide a complete example. (A side note: Heiko's answer works because the second argument of `\colordefine` is a single token, so `\expandafter` works: yours are several tokens, so you need another approach).

Comment: Thank you, you're quite right, the actual `\colorGet` macro uses the `xstring` package for its `\IfStrEqCase` macro, but I've since realised that it's not actually necessary, and I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @pbc The simplification makes this into an XY-question and with little sense in it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the MWE as given it is sufficient to first expand the `\colorGet` macro into a temporary command and then use that as argument for `\definecolor`. The solution may need to be expanded (pun intended...) if `xstring` is used for the `\colorGet` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\colorGet}[2]{D3523C} % A macro which returns a different hex-code for each combination of arguments, simplified for this example.
\newcommand{\colordefine}[2]{%
    \edef\tmpcolor{#2}%
    \definecolor{#1}{HTML}{\tmpcolor}%
}

\begin{document}
    \colordefine{mycolor}{\colorGet{SchemeName}{ColourName}}
    \textcolor{mycolor}{colored text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\newcommand{\colorGet}[2]{D3523C} % A macro which returns a different hex-code for each combination of arguments, simplified for this example.
\newcommand{\colordefine}[2]{%
    \expandafter\colordefineAux#2{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\colordefineAux}[2]{%
    \definecolor{#2}{HTML}{#1}%
}
%
\begin{document}
    \colordefine{mycolor}{\colorGet{SchemeName}{ColourName}}
\end{document}
```

`\colordefine{mycolor}{\colorGet{SchemeName}{ColourName}}` yields:

`\expandafter\colordefineAux\colorGet{SchemeName}{ColourName}{mycolor}`, which in turn yields:

`\colordefineAux D3523C{mycolor}`, which in turn yields:

`\definecolor{3}{HTML}{D}523C{mycolor}`

You may have realized that probably either `\colorGet` should return its result nested in braces or the call to `\colorGet` should take place nested in braces.

In any case `\colorGet` must be fully expandable, i.e., may itself not yield tokens that form whatsoever temporary assignments and therefore actually are not part of the HTML-color-specification.

In order to work around this restriction I suggest `\colorGet` to take an (optional) argument where you can specify tokens where the result is to be appended to for further processing:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorGet}[3][\@firstofone]{#1{D3523C}} % A macro which returns a different hex-code for each combination of arguments, simplified for this example.
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\colorGet[\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}]{SchemeName}{ColourName}
\end{document}
```