# Change color in beamer theme to user defined

Tags: beamer, color

I would like to change the color of my headings and bullet points from the default blue to my own blue. I have put in the correct rgb (it works with documents like PowerPoint), but somehow my beamer presentation has a different shade of blue than the blue I get in PowerPoint with the same rgb. How can that be? What can I change in my code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\definecolor{mine}{rgb}{0,138,171}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=mine,fg=white}    
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=mine,fg=white}    
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=mine,fg=white}    
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=mine,fg=white}    
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=mine}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=mine} 
\begin{document}
\title{My title}  
\author{My name}
\date{\today} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\definecolor{mine}{0,138,171}` is not correct. It should be `\definecolor{mine}{RGB}{0,138,171}`. Note that `rgb` and `RGB` have different meanings.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to welcome you to TeX.SX! So: welcome! To your question, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239461/color-rgb-in-latex

Comment: Thank you so much! My color code was in indeed for RGB and not rgb. Didn't realize there was a difference.

Comment: Since you seem know a lot about beamer presentations, could you tell me whether I defined by fonts correctly? I want Montserrat Bold for titles/headlines and everything else in Roboto Light:
    - \usepackage{fontspec}
    - \setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontfamily{Montserrat}\bf}
    - \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\fontfamily{Montserrat}\bf}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle{family=\fontfamily{Montserrat}\bf}
    - \setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\fontfamily{Roboto}\lf}

Comment: This should be considered a new question. However: First you load the package with `\usepackage{fontspec}`. Then you assign the fonts to the font families with `\setmainfont{Montserrat}` and `\setsansfont{Roboto}`. Then you can use `\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\rmfamily}` or `\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\sffamily}` to assign the font families to the title or normal text. Make sure, both fonts are installed on your system.